# Erro ValueError: 1 columns passed, passed data had 12 columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Eu estou tentando fazer um DataFrame mas recebo esse erro:ValueError: 1 columns passed, passed data had 12 columns. Aqui o meu código:

```
import pandas as pd 
colunas = ['Legenda']
conteudo2 = [['Pontos Ganhos','Vitórias','Empates','Derrotas','Saldo de Gols','Gols   Pró','Gols Contra','Chance de campeão','Chance de Libertadores','Chance de Pré Libertadores','Chance de Sul Americana','Chance de Rebaixamento']]
legenda = pd.DataFrame(conteudo2,index=['PG', 'V', 'E', 'D', 'SG', 'GP', 'GC', 'AP','CC', 'CL','CPL','CSA','CR'],columns=colunas)
```

Answer (score 3):

O primeiro erro para seu caso ocorre aqui, onde você passa uma 'lista de lista'

```
conteudo2 = [['Pontos Ganhos','Vitórias','Empates','Derrotas','Saldo de Gols','Gols   Pró','Gols Contra','Chance de campeão','Chance de Libertadores','Chance de Pré Libertadores','Chance de Sul Americana','Chance de Rebaixamento']]
```

O segundo erro ocorre pois você tem mais índices que conteudo2.

---

Código

```
import pandas as pd 

colunas = ['Legenda']
conteudo2 = ['Pontos Ganhos','Vitórias','Empates','Derrotas','Saldo de Gols',
             'Gols Pró','Gols Contra','Aproveitamento','Chance de campeão',
             'Chance de Libertadores','Chance de Pré Libertadores',
             'Chance de Sul Americana','Chance de Rebaixamento']

legenda = pd.DataFrame(conteudo2,index=['PG', 'V', 'E', 'D',
                                        'SG', 'GP', 'GC',
                                        'AP','CC', 'CL',
                                        'CPL','CSA','CR'],columns=colunas)
```

Saída

```
    Legenda
PG  Pontos Ganhos
V   Vitórias
E   Empates
D   Derrotas
SG  Saldo de Gols
GP  Gols Pró
GC  Gols Contra
AP  Aproveitamento
CC  Chance de campeão
CL  Chance de Libertadores
CPL Chance de Pré Libertadores
CSA Chance de Sul Americana
CR  Chance de Rebaixamento
```